# BigDecimal loses precision after multiplication

Tags: ruby, floating-point

I'm getting a strange behaviour with `BigDecimal` in ruby. Why does this print false?

```
require 'bigdecimal'

a = BigDecimal.new('100')
b = BigDecimal.new('5.1')
c = a / b
puts c * b == a #false
```

Comment: This is really "BigDecimal loses precision after division".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, and not at all strange.

`BigDecimal` does not guarantee infinite accuracy, it allows you to specify *arbitrary* accuracy, which is not the same thing. The value `100/5.1` cannot be expressed with complete precision using floating point internal representation. Doesn't matter how many bits are used.

A "big rational" approach could achieve it - but would not give you access to some functions e.g. square roots.

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html

```
# require 'rational' necessary only in Ruby 1.8
a = 100.to_r
b = '5.1'.to_r
c = a / b
c * b == a
# => true
```

Comment: The  `require 'rational'` is unnecessary in Ruby >= 1.9.

Answer (score 3):

BigDecimal doesn't claim to have infinite precision, it just provides support for precisions outside the normal floating point ranges:

> `BigDecimal` provides similar support for very large or very accurate floating point numbers.

But BigDecimal values still have a finite number of significant digits, hence the [`precs` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-precs):

> **precs**
>
> Returns an Array of two Integer values.
>
> The first value is the current number of significant digits in the BigDecimal. The second value is the maximum number of significant digits for the BigDecimal.

You can see things starting to go awry if you look at your `c`:

```
>> c.to_s
=> "0.19607843137254901960784313725E2"
```

That's a nice clean rational number but BigDecimal doesn't know that, it is still stuck seeing `c` as a finite string of digits.

If you use Rational instead, you'll get the results you're expecting:

```
>> a = Rational(100)
>> b = Rational(51, 10)
>> c * b == a
=> true
```

Of course, this trickery only applies if you are working with Rational numbers so anything fancy (such as roots or trigonometry) is out of bounds.